# VirtualHosts in Apache using xampp

Tags: apache, xampp

I have an application in Python to which I access via an html document running in Apache, using xampp. I have to type "desktop-6oirdq3:8081/db.html" from a remote device to get to the file. I want to use a friendlier URL and easier to remember. For that, I'm trying to create a VirtualHost in Apache. The path for the file is:

C:/xampp/htdocs/Dashboard/db.html

These are some lines of my httpd.conf:

```
Listen 8081

DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/Dashboard"

<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/Dashboard">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted
</Directory>

<IfModule dir_module>
    DirectoryIndex index.php index.pl index.cgi index.asp index.shtml index.html index.htm \
                   default.php default.pl default.cgi default.asp default.shtml default.html  
                   default.htm \
                   home.php home.pl home.cgi home.asp home.shtml home.html home.htm index.py app.py
</IfModule>




Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf
ScriptInterpreterSource Registry-Strict
```

In the httpd-vhosts.conf I have:

```
NameVirtualHost 192.168.1.134:8081
<VirtualHost 192.168.1.134:8081>
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/Dashboard"
    ServerName dashboard.com
</VirtualHost>
<Directory "C:/xampp/htdocs/Dashboard">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    Require all granted
 </Directory>
```

And finally in the hosts file:

```
::1 localhost
192.168.1.134 dashboard.com
```

The thing is, when I activate Apache, and type "dashboard.com" in the searchbar, it says "This site can't be reached". I have no idea what is wrong. Followed several tutorials but don't work it out. Do you have any idea? If you need more code I'll provide it
Thank you!